# What can be the optimized query for this?

Tags: mysql

I have stuck in small query. There is a table named Table_Activities.

**Table_Activities** (`Act_id`, `Dat`e, `Activity_name`, `description`).

We need to generate a report out of this. User will choose the **month** and **year** for which he wants to generate the report from drop down list.

We need to display All the activities for that month and year group by Activity name.

Example - User Chooses **June** and **2012**.

Report will be-

**Gardening**

```
01/06/2012 - They have planted 100 trees.
14/06/2012 - something
27/06/2012 - something
```

**Training**

```
02/06/2012 - Detail description
15/06/2012 - something
28/06/2012 - something
```

My question is what will be the mysql query to fetch data in this format??

Comment: can you post the schema of your table(s)?

Comment: Is `They have planted 100 trees.` a description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select `Date`,description from tm_activities 
where month(`Date`)='6' and year(`Date`)='2012' 
order by Activity_name,`date`
```

To return an exact format as indicated in your question, please try below:

```
select concat(if(actdate='',activity_name,date_format(actdate,'%d/%m/%y')),if(description<>'',concat(' - ',description),'')) as labelm from
(
(select ActDate,description,activity_name from tm_activities where month(ActDate)='6' and year(ActDate)='2012' 
) 
union all
(Select distinct '','',activity_name from tm_activities where month(ActDate)='6' and year(ActDate)='2012')
)m order by activity_name,actdate
;
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee853/1)

Output as below:

```
Gardening
01/06/12 - They have planted 100 trees.
27/06/12 - Gar 2
Training
12/06/12 - Training 1
28/06/12 - Traning 2
30/06/12 - Traning 3
```

Comment: Great Solution. Hats Off to you.

Comment: Hi Sel, How can we display the same on HTML page, using php. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you meant by display the same on html page?

Answer (score 1):

To get data for particular month and year group by Activity_name try this:

```
SELECT Activity_name
,GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(Date,"%d/%m/%Y")) as `Date`
,GROUP_CONCAT(Description) as `Description`
FROM Table_Activities 
WHERE MONTH(Date) = MONTH('2012-06-01')
AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR('2012-06-01')
GROUP BY Activity_name
```

**Output**

```
ACTIVITY_NAME    DATE                    DESCRIPTION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gardening        01/06/2012,27/06/2012   They have planted 100 trees.,Description3
Training         12/06/2012,28/06/2012   Description2,Description4
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0609/10)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    DATE_FORMAT('date_column',"%D/%M/%Y") as `Date`,
    other_column  
from Table_Activities 
where Month(Date) = Month('2012-06-01')
AND Year(Date) = Year('2012-06-01')
```